# How to best format an HTML form like this where user can dynamically add subfields? (table? list? css3?)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a form like the one pictured below:

[image]

I see many ways how to use table, css, lists, but want to know how to best implement what I have pictured. The idea is that "Student(s)" has a Name and Age associated with it and by clicking on "Add Row" link, a new pair of Name and Age fields would appear right under it.

If someone can suggest to me the best way to accomplishing this so that I don't have alignment problems where the field label is to the left of the input fields, I would greatly appreciate it. I know it would be simple with tables, but wanted to see if there is a tableless solution suitable for the modern age of HTML5/CSS3.

I went off of this 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-cross-browser-html5-forms/

But had problems tweaking it to look like what i pictured above. If someone can help show me how to best achieve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: HTML5 is not anti-table, it's just pro-semantics. In this case, it would be quite fine to use a `<table>` as the information is, in fact, a table of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this script:

```
 var lastUsed=0;

function addGroup()
{
   lastused++;
   namstr='StName'+lastused;
   agestr='StAge'+lastused;
   str='<div> Name: <input type="text" name="'+namstr+'" value="">
   Age: <input type="text" name="'+agestr+'" value=""></div>';
   document.getElementById('formBlock').innerHTML+=str;
}
```

With this HTML:

```
<form name="myform" action... etc>
<div id="formBlock">
    Class Name: <input type="text" name="clName" value=''>
    <div> Name: <input type="text" name="StName0" value="">
    Age: <input type="text" name="StAge0" value=""></div>
</div>
<textarea>....etc

</form>
```

It should add them just fine.  I didn't include any styling because we don't have a page layout. The styling should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide your page into blocks.
Each block will be the div element .
With the CSS you will control the layout and size.
I think in you case it wll be 4 divs

Answer (score 0):

For HTML structure, simply use a div to enclose the row and labels & inputs for the elements:

```
<div>
<label for="name-1">Name</label><input type="text" id="name-1" />
<label for="age-1">Age</label><input type="text" id="age-1" />
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add Row" id="addRow" />
```

In the script to add a new row, you'll need to increment the `ids` and `for` attributes when adding.